# Lttng - Syscalls support on MIPS?

Tags: mips, system-calls, lttng

I am having a trouble in getting the lttng-modules integrated for my MIPS-32, kernel-3.4. I see that the lttng code looks for the file - asm/syscall.h. This file is not available for MIPS. How can I fix it? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for recognizing MIPS32 system calls has been recently merged in the lttng-modules git.

See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.tracing.lttng.devel/7730

Comment: How to check out this source?

Comment: The lttng-modules git is available here.

http://git.lttng.org/?p=lttng-modules.git;a=summary

Answer (score 0):

this capability is not supported by MIPS architecture